# How to get binary data of an image

Tags: c#, asp.net

Actually I upload a image and then cropped the image using Imazen.crop. I can get the binary data of the uploaded image, but not of the cropped image i.e,., the image after I crop which need to be stored into the database(SQL Server).

But I need the binary data of cropped image.Below is the code where I crop the Image:

```
enter code here

.aspx:
<pre>
    <%@ Register Assembly="Imazen.Crop" Namespace="Imazen.Crop" TagPrefix="ic" %>
<ic:CropImage ID="CropImage1" runat="server" Image="Image1" CanvasWidth="300" />

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Crop"   OnClick="btnCrop_Click" />

<asp:Image ID="Result" runat="server" Visible="false"  />
</pre>

.cs file:
<pre>
protected void btnCrop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       //Show the Result Image control 
       Result.Visible = true;
       //Assign the image url from CropImage control
       Result.ImageUrl = CropImage1.CroppedUrl;
   }
</pre>
```

Comment: where are you cropping the image?

Comment: Im using Imazen.Crop.dll.

Comment: <pre><%@ Register Assembly="Imazen.Crop" Namespace="Imazen.Crop" TagPrefix="ic" %>                         <ic:CropImage ID="CropImage1" runat="server" Image="Image1" CanvasWidth="300" />
            
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Crop" OnClick="btnCrop_Click" />
            <h3>The result</h3>
            <asp:Image ID="Result" runat="server" Visible="false"  /></pre>Here I crop the image and display it in the Result. Now I need to get binary data for the resultant Image.

Comment: Put this code in your post.

Comment: So presumably at some point you give `img` to the `CropImage1` control? You haven't shown the connection between your uploaded image and your cropped image. What happens when brnCrop is clicked? Your flow of control is unclear.

Comment: Result.ImageUrl = CropImage1.CroppedUrl; Here I Can Display the Cropped Image In Result Image

Comment: <pre>protected void btnCrop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           //Show the Result Image control 
           Result.Visible = true;
           //Assign the image url from CropImage control
           Result.ImageUrl = CropImage1.CroppedUrl;}</pre>

Comment: as per the docs at https://github.com/nathanaeljones/cropimage under "Getting the result", you can either get the URL, or save to disk. If you save to disk you could then open the file and get the bytes that way. (Then you could delete the file again if you don't need it). Are you trying to store it in a database? If so, consider just saving the file to a path, and just saving the path into the database - this is generally more efficient.

Comment: Is that possible to retrieve all the images from the database by only using the path but not the binary data format in ASP>Net?

Comment: yes - use the path to construct a HTML `<img>` tag. In ASP.NET you can use the `<asp:Image>` control. Bear in mind you need to use a relative path (not the path on disk), and the images need to be stored somewhere that's accessible by the webserver.